# Persistent IPC between Bash script and C++

Tags: c++, linux, bash, ipc

Problem:
There is a **C application** that calls a **Bash script** each time an event happens. And there is also a **C++ application** that needs to track down those events. The **C++ application** is driven by a select() event loop. What would be the most simplest IPC to implement between **Bash script** and **C++ application**?

```
C Application ---Each time calls Bash script---> Bash application ---???---> C++ Application
```

Few solutions that came into my mind:

1. To use TCP networking sockets, but this would mean that select will have to handle events for both Listening and Actual sockets
2. To use Named pipes, but once the bash script terminates then the other end of the pipe is closed as well

Is there something simpler that would allow me to use only one File Descriptor in select()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Unix datagram](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/unix.7.html) or UDP socket would do. The bash script would just send a datagram to that socket (you may need a helper program that does `sendmsg()` or `sendto()` on that socket, such as [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) or netcat/nc). The receiver does not need to accept connections for datagram sockets, once it is ready for read there must be a datagram waiting. Subject to datagram length restrictions.

Comment: +1 Because datagram sockets do not have to mess with Accept(). Also according to the man page Unix domain datagram sockets are reliable, while UDP sockets are not. So that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: I think my proposal of using simple pipes works better here because it uses less resources, does not touch the filesystem and is doable entirely in bash (without having to use external programs for `sendmsg()`/`sendto()`).

Comment: The helper program may be not necessary (i haven't tried), since the socket file name is the destination address, so `echo "abc" > socket` may suffice.

Comment: Instead of "echo abc > socket" one must use either socat or nc (version 4.4+?, where nc allows to use -U and -u both at the same time). Because you can't write in a socket just like in a regular file with redirect symbol.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it with a unnamed `pipe()`. Remember: In UNIX file descriptors remain open after `fork()` and `execve()` in both processes! So you can use `pipe()` to get a pair of file descriptors and then write into the fd using bash's `echo >&FD` where `FD` is the file descriptor number.

That is very straight forward, easy and uses less resources than anything else I assume. The use of `select()` is no problem, just do not block on `read()` is I do in my sample but `select()` on `pfds[0]`.

Sample program (spawns 10 bash processes which send 'hello work, my pid: XXX', waiting 1s between spawning the processes. The sample only uses one pipe for all the children. I changed it that way because the author asked about that. In practice, I would *NOT* recommend it (see the note below the sample)):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int pfds[2];
    pid_t p;

    assert(0 == pipe(pfds));

    p = fork();
    if (p == 0) {
        unsigned int i;
        char str_fd[3];            char *env[] = {NULL};
        char *args[] = { "/bin/bash", "-c", "echo >&$1 hello world, my pid: $$"
                       , "-s", str_fd, NULL};
        snprintf(str_fd, 3, "%d", pfds[1]);
        str_fd[2] = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            p = fork();
            if(0 == p) {
                assert(0 ==
                       execve( "/bin/bash", (char *const*)args
                             , (char *const*)env));
            } else if (0 > p) {
                perror("fork");
                exit(1);
            } else {
                wait(NULL);
            }   
            sleep(1);
        }   
    } else if(p > 0) {
        char *buf = malloc(100);
        ssize_t sz; 
        printf("fd is %d, <hit Ctrl+C to exit>\n", pfds[1]);
        while(0 < ( sz = read(pfds[0], buf, 100))) {
            buf[99] = 0;
            printf("received: '%s'\n", buf);
        }   
        free(buf);
        if (0 == sz) {
            fprintf(stderr, "EOF!");
        } else {
            perror("read from bash failed");
        }   
        wait(NULL);
    } else {
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(1);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

sample program output:

```
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out 
fd is 4, <hit Ctrl+C to exit>
received: 'hello world, my pid: 779
'
received: 'hello world, my pid: 780
'
received: 'hello world, my pid: 781
'
received: 'hello world, my pid: 782
'
received: 'hello world, my pid: 783
'
received: 'hello world, my pid: 784
'
received: 'hello world, my pid: 785
'
received: 'hello world, my pid: 786
'
received: 'hello world, my pid: 787
'
received: 'hello world, my pid: 788
'
```

works, bashs send 'hello world, my pid: XXX\n' to parent process all using one pipe :-).

Nevertheless that seems to work as the demo program shows (should be ok using the POSIX semantics and tested under Linux and MacOS X), I would recommend using one `pipe()` per child process. That will lead to fewer problems and running more than one child process at a time is possible, too. `select()` or `epoll()` (if you have MANY child processes) are your friend.

Since `pipe()` is very cheap, in particular compared to bash!, I would definitely not use the same pipe for more than more than one child (as my updated sample now does).

Comment: The Bash process is created each time an event happens. Once the first instance of Bash process terminates then the pipe is closed on both its ends. This would mean that I need to quickly reopen pipe from the C++ application, right?

Comment: I slightly changed the sample program. I now does spawn 10 bash processes which all send to the pipe. It is always the same pipe. This will only work if there is always just one bash process sending to that pipe running at a time!

Comment: @Ansis Atteka, as you can see in my demo it works with just one pipe. But since pipe() is very cheap, you could also use one pipe() per bash. Then you'll get no problem when more than one shell is running simultaneously. In the case you have MANY file desriptors to listen on, use `epoll()`.

Comment: +1 for hard work :) But anyway I needed IPC between Bash script and C++ application not between C application (that creates the Bash script) and the Bash script itself (see the problem statement). Unavoidably with this approach I would have to use named pipes (hence involve filesystem) because in my case Bash script does not now the fd in advance. Also wouldn't it really close the pipe because fork() is not an option to me...

Comment: @Ansis Atteka: You have to use `fork()` to spawn processes in UNIX. Even if you use `system()` it will do `fork()`+`execve()`. For my approach I passed to fd to the bash script using an argument (`$1`), if you don't like that, you can use a file, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lightweight messaging queue like [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/). I think you would use its PUSH-PULL mechanism. Your C program or the bash script pushes events while the C++ application pulls them. ZeroMQ is written in C but, besides many others, there exists a C++ and a Python binding for it. See [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Divide-and-Conquer) for a PUSH-PULL example.

Comment: +1. I also considered this approach, but it seemed too overweight for my problem (at least initially). I was looking for something that does not add extra dependencies.